# Upload Array of Images to the Node.js server in IOS

Tags: ios, arrays, image-uploading, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload multiple images to server in the form of array using NSURLConnection (multipart/form-data). But I am unable to send. Just one image is being sent to server even from the array of multiple images. I have tried many solutions, but nothing working for me. Server is written in Node.js.

```
NSString *first_name;
        NSString *last_name;
        NSString *image_name;
        NSData *imageData;

        //-- Convert string into URL
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://delta-homelab.com/api/order/test"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *boundary = @"14737809831466499882746641449";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        //-- Append data into posr url using following method
        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];


        NSArray *imagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Pin Code"])],
                                [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Pin Code"])],
                                [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Pin Code"])], nil];

        NSData *images = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:imagesArray];

        NSMutableData *postData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:[images length] + 512];
        [postData setData:images];

        //-- For Sending text

        //-- "firstname" is keyword form service
        //-- "first_name" is the text which we have to send
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",@"firstname"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",first_name] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        //-- "lastname" is keyword form service
        //-- "last_name" is the text which we have to send
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",@"lastname"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",last_name] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        //-- For sending image into service (send as imagedata)



        //-- "image_name" is file name of the image (we can set custom name)
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"images\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",image_name] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Pin Code"])]];
        [body appendData:postData];



        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        //-- Sending data into server through URL
        [request setHTTPBody:body];

        //-- Getting response form server
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

        //-- JSON Parsing with response data
        NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        NSLog(@"Result = %@",result);
```

Comment: Could you post the code that you did try so we can help you from there?

Comment: I have put the code in question. @vqdave